# HTTP POST request with JSON

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I'm having problems with JSON Serialization in swift.

My code looks like:

```
var username = "xcode"
var password = "pass"

let json = ["username":username, "password":password]
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myServer")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = jsonData
```

My problem is that when I make the petition to the server (which works fine), it returns me this line of code:

```
responseString = Optional("{\"username\":[\"This field is required.\"],\"password\":[\"This field is required.\"]}")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the response not looking correct, what prob you facing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be:

```
var username = "xcode"
var password = "pass"
let json = ["username":username, "password":password]
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://10.192.118.193:8000/users/")!)

request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = jsonData
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```